# how to pass the pointer in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing a mini quiz game. In the opening xib, i get the preferred username using the methods below and pass it to the model(ModelUnit):

```
  //intro.h

    @interface introViewController : UIViewController{

        ModelUnit * modl;

    }


 //intro.m

    -(ModelUnit *) modl{

    if(!modl){
        modl = [[ModelUnit alloc] init];
    }
    return modl;
}

- (IBAction)nickEntered:(UITextField *)sender{

    [[self modl] setName:[sender text]];

    .....

}
```

However, when i try to create another pointer which points to the ModelUnit in the sequentially last xib, it returns the username as null. So i assume it has to be the same pointer to reach the same location. How can i go about it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you want to address the same object (not just one of the same class), you need to create the object once, set a pointer to it, and somehow pass that same pointer value to all the methods than need to reference the object.  This is basic object-oriented programming, which you should have down cold before you try to code in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not even setting it right. Look how you refer to your 'modl' in two different ways in the intro.m file

[self modl] refers to a property called 'modl'  normal use of 'modl' refers to a variable like you declared in your interface.

This suggests you are probably not even storing the username in the 'modl' object you created. Or that you have two 'modl'  objects. (Would have to see complete code to know for sure)

To be able to access the 'modl' from outside this view/class you would probably have to create a getter that returns the 'modl'.  You could do this by hand or declare a property to use instead of a variable (@property) which automatically comes with a getter and setter. This still requires you to have a reference to the Intro object. If not you will have to store it somewhere else, or pass it along like Hot Licks suggested.